# How to append one ByteBuffer to other?

Tags: java, java-io, bytebuffer

Suppose that I have 2 ByteBuffer containing some bytes in it...
How would be the best way to append all the content of one ByteBuffer with other?
I'm doing this but it throws a BufferUnderFlowException:

```
ByteBuffer allData = ByteBuffer.allocate(999999);
ByteBuffer buff = null;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    buff = aMethodThatReturnsAFilledByteBuffer();
    allData.put(buff);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put(java.nio.ByteBuffer) The issue is in a call to .get() in aMethodThatReturnsAFilledByteBuffer()

Answer (score 2):

Here how it works:

```java
ByteBuffer.allocate(byteBuffer.limit() + byteBuffer2.limit())
          .put(byteBuffer)
          .put(byteBuffer2)
          .rewind()
```

Using bytebuffer limit() here, since that's the point where the byteBuffers is filled to.  Using capacity() should also work, but can allocate more bytes, than you strictly need.

For limit and capacity I looked see this post: [What is the difference between limit and capacity in ByteBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148729/what-is-the-difference-between-limit-and-capacity-in-bytebuffer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flip()` the source buffer prior to any operating that implies a `get()` operation, such as a `write()`, or using it as the source of a `put()` operation into another buffer. You also need to `compact()` it afterwards to restore its state.

Comment: an example here might be helpful?