# What is the difference between limit and capacity in ByteBuffer?

Tags: java

What is the difference between limit and capacity in Java's [java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Its best illustrated [**HERE in this article**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/buffers.html#capacity-position-limit): They are mainly different depending on the mode,

- In **Write Mode**, Capacity and Limit are Same.
- But in **Read** mode Limit means the limit of how much data you can read from the data

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, but it is describing a `Buffer` (which `ByteBuffer` ISA `Buffer`) but doesn't seem to apply to `ByteBuffer` directly. Specifically, you can both read and write to a `ByteBuffer` and there is only `byteBuffer.limit()`, so is that treated as Read Mode or Write Mode?

Comment: For others who are new to `ByteBuffer` (like myself): after researching further, it looks like `ByteBuffer` starts in "Write" mode, until you call `byteBuffer.flip()` which puts it into "Read" mode. Then, you call `byteBuffer.clear()` to put it back into "Write" mode.

Comment: or byteBuffer.compact() - which, to my knowledge, also puts it back to "Write" mode.

Answer (score 43):

`ByteBuffer` does not have a `length()` method. Instead it has a several length-like concepts:

```
mark <= position <= limit <= capacity
```

`capacity` = Inside the `ByteBuffer`, there is a backing `byte[]` or something that behaves much like one. The capacity is its size. The capacity indexes the first slot past the end of the buffer.

`limit` = When filling the buffer, the limit is the same as the capacity. When emptying the buffer, it is one past the last filled byte in the buffer.

`position` = When filling the buffer, the position points just past the last byte filled in the buffer. When emptying the buffer, the position points just past the last byte written from the buffer.

`mark` The mark is an optional bookmark to let you record an interesting spot in the `ByteBuffer` that you want to return to later. When you take a `mark()` it records current position, and when you call `reset()` it restores that position.

I hope this helps. Also an example can be seen over here: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bytebuffer.html

Source: [Oracle Java Buffer reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) - See 'Invariants' section.

Comment: Good answer but terrible citation. You should cite Java documentation, Oracle tutorials, etc., not arbitrary third-party sites.

Answer (score 8):

capacity is buffer's max size which is determined on buffer creation and never changes, limit is the actual size which can be changed. You cannot read or write beyond limit.

```
    ByteBuffer b= ByteBuffer.allocate(10); // capacity = 10, limit = 10
    b.limit(1);    //set limit to 1
    b.put((byte)1);
    b.put((byte)1); //causes java.nio.BufferOverflowException
```